# Does [契る] apply to marriage?

Tags: context

Like is this used in context of marriage?

Comment: https://kotobank.jp/word/契る-565485

Answer (score 1):

契る is a verb meaning 1."to pledge oneself / vow", "to promise/assure/swear that you (will) do something",  and 2. "to be in a sexual relationship (as a married/unmarried couple) " and it is in a way an old word.
In short, yes you can use it in a context that means a couple getting married, but it would be more proper to say "夫婦の契りを交わす", to vow to become husband and wife or
"結婚の契りを交わす".

Other examples "将来を契る" - Pledge the future to each other (to marry each other)
"再会を契る" - to promise to see each other in the future

Comment: hello? what does 私と永遠に契るわ mean?